# angularjs testing with selenium ide

Tags: angularjs, selenium, jenkins-pipeline, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

Is it possible to test AngularJs code by generating selenium scripts by recording test cases using browser(via selenium IDE) and exporting it to Java code and find out the code coverage so that there is no need to write the test cases manually for continuous integration purpose?

Answer (score 0):

The [Selenium IDE documentation](https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/code-export/) describes how to export `.side` files to WebDriver code.

> You can export either a test or suite of tests to WebDriver code by right-clicking on a test or a suite, selecting `Export`, choosing your target language, and clicking `Export`.

[image: export screenshot]